# PHP - Replace page ID selected from MySQL database with alias name in URL

Tags: php, mysql, url, alias

Not sure if title explains my problem well...

I have a site with a lot of pages (I call them "sections"). When users click on a page link, PHP script selects section content and infos from MySQL database, and show them to user. To avoid the display of section ID in browser addresses bar (the page is loaded through the knowledge of section ID in database), there is one different file associated to each section. In these files, PHP code passes ID to $_GET variable, and script loads section. The displayed URL is so `http://site_domain/path/to/file_name.php`.

Is there a way to avoid the creation of real file and to show, for example, an alias in URL? I thought to add a new column "alias" in database table sections to replace it in URL.

Hope my English and the explanation is clear...

Comment: Look up '.htdocs' for URL Rewrites.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create some sort of general controller which is a page, lets call it index.php and in that page you can pass some information about the section on your website through some GET parameter.

For example: http://andreswebsite.com/index.php?section=home

And then in your index.php code you can redirect the user to that specific section. You can have the section name in your database so no need to pass the ID.

Also you can look at the Apache mod_rewrite module which I think it could help you (I don't know if you use Apache as your web server)

Here is the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

I hope this has helped you.